# issue with generate_tfrecord.py script

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

i have been struggling to solve this issue for quite some time now. i am using a script for converting .csv files to .record files to be used for object detection. the script is commonly known to all as generate_tfrecord.py. whenever i run the script, i encounter the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/MSI-GF63/Desktop/raccoon_dataset-master/generate_tfrecord.py", line 101, in
tf.app.run()
File "C:\Users\MSI-GF63\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
_run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
File "C:\Users\MSI-GF63\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299, in run
_run_main(main, args)
File "C:\Users\MSI-GF63\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250, in _run_main
sys.exit(main(argv))
File "C:/Users/MSI-GF63/Desktop/raccoon_dataset-master/generate_tfrecord.py", line 86, in main
print(FLAGS.output_path)
File "C:\Users\MSI-GF63\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\flags.py", line 85, in getattr
return wrapped.getattr(name)
File "C:\Users\MSI-GF63\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\flags_flagvalues.py", line 473, in getattr
raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: output_path
```

can someone please help me with this? i am using windows and running the script on Pycharm

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Are you setting an `output_path`?

Comment: i posted the code as an answer @ashishmishra

Answer (score 0):

@ashishmishra @Dave Cameron This is the script i am using.

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict


flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input=./data/train_labels.csv', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir=./data/train_images', '', 'Path to images')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path=./data/train.record', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'BAD':
        return 1
    else:
        None


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), 
 gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
     }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(FLAGS.image_dir)
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```